Harry Potter fanfic with a Luna/Harry/Hermione pairing where she expounds at great length about how various wizarding spells are about sex
Hogwarts: So why aren't the kids "doing it"? recently popped up and it made a fanfic pop into my mind, partially inspired by "splinching" showing up in a different story that mildly crossed over with Harry Potter. It was a fanfic that had a least a few dozen chapters, and I remember it did have a complete ending. Screwball comedy, no pun intended. I forget a lot of the main plot, to be honest, but there was a running gag that Luna had decided that couple of Harry and Hermione had to become a throuple (I don't remember if she used that term specifically), and kept inserted herself into their life in one suggestive way or another. I remember, at one point, her going on at length about various bits of wizarding lore being used for sexual purposes. Harry and Hermione, neither having grown up in the Wizarding World, didn't quite believe her also weren't entirely certain if maybe she was right. The only bit that I remember specifically was her stating that "splinching" where body parts are painlessly separated during an Apparation fail, was an intentional thing so that people could leave particular bits of their anatomy with a loved one with the idea that it could be put to good use. I forget the others, although I think that the Engorgement charm was charm was used for body part enlargement. As regards her other antics, I remember at least one incident where they woke up to find that she'd slipped into their bed (naked) and one where they came back to where they were living to find that she was in a state of self-bondage on the bed, whereupon I think they largely ignored her while they went about their business. Near the end of the fic, they have need of her family magic (which I think might have involved some sort of soul-binding, and which they planned to use to deal with the fragment of Voldemort in Harry, and it turns out that exchanging family magics like that was an implicit proposal, which leaves Luna deliriously happy and them bemusedly resigned to that she'd wormed her way in.
I think I may have read it over a decade ago on fanfiction.net. I don't remember exactly when the stories are set, although I suspect that it was probably near the end of their time at Hogwarts because I don't remember much schooling involved, and it would put the characters in a much less icky age range for what they get up to. Oh, other little tidbits that are popping into my head, Luna claims at one point that her family name is well deserved ("love good") and at some point Harry learns some trick for detecting and opening hidden compartments, and decides to test it on his bed in the Hogwarts dorms, which leads to him finding some decades of cached contraband from former students. And at some point, Harry and Hermione are wearing silk outfits (to insulate them from magic?) and someone (maybe not Luna) catches them in them and assumes it's a sex thing.

I remember reading this at some point; unfortunately, I, too, forget the title. Perhaps try looking through TVTropes' FanficRec pages? I'm pretty sure I saw it there, but it's been a while.

This sounds like "Larceny, Lechery and Luna Lovegood" by the author Rorschach's Blot. It has been a while since I've read it, so not clear on all the details. The following points match:

Exchanging family magic is seen as a proposal
Harry and Hermione are caught in silk outfits and it is being mistaken for sexual roleplay. They are caught by either Tonks or another auror.
Luna mentions something about one of her ancestors seducing a follower of Grindelwald. This lead to the name Lovegood
Luna finds various ways to end up in a relation with both Harry and Hermione. Showing up in their bed naked is one, possibly through some kind of bed portal.
The Potter family magic involves wards. In one of the first chapters Harry finds all kinds of contraband of an adult nature in either his bed or his trunk.

The story dates from 2008, so the time frame also matches.

Hah! That brings back all sorts of memories. And... I'm also remembering that the story had a decent amount of problematic bits too.
